# Getting an error in my solidity code : CompileError: ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'event'

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to develop a smart contract for ticket booking system. I am getting the following error

CompileError: ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'event'
--> project:/contracts/TicketBooking.sol:28:22:
|
28 |         Event memory event = events[_id];

THe solidity code :

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract TicketBooking {
    
    struct Event {
        string name;
        string description;
        uint256 startDate;
        uint256 endDate;
        uint256 totalTickets;
        uint256 price;
        mapping (uint256 => bool) tickets;
    }
    Event[] events;
    mapping (uint256 => Event) events;
    address payable public admin;
    
    constructor() {
        admin = payable(msg.sender);
    }
    function getEvent(uint256 _id) public view returns (string memory, string memory, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        Event memory event = events[_id];
        uint256 availableTickets = event.totalTickets;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < event.totalTickets; i++) {
            if (event.tickets[i]) {
                availableTickets--;
            }
        }
        return (event.name, event.description, event.startDate, event.endDate, event.totalTickets, availableTickets, event.price);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract TicketBooking {
    
    struct Event {
        string name;
        string description;
        uint256 startDate;
        uint256 endDate;
        uint256 totalTickets;
        uint256 price;
        mapping (uint256 => bool) tickets;
    }
    
    Event[] public events;
    mapping (uint256 => Event) public eventMapping;
    
    address payable public admin;
    
    constructor() {
        admin = payable(msg.sender);
    }
    
    function getEvent(uint256 _id) public view returns (string memory, string memory, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        Event storage selectedEvent = eventMapping[_id];
        uint256 availableTickets = selectedEvent.totalTickets;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < selectedEvent.totalTickets; i++) {
            if (selectedEvent.tickets[i]) {
                availableTickets--;
            }
        }
        return (selectedEvent.name, selectedEvent.description, selectedEvent.startDate, selectedEvent.endDate, selectedEvent.totalTickets, availableTickets, selectedEvent.price);
    }
}
```

Note:
memory keyword cannot use for mapping -> change to storage

In addition, use 2 different names. I change the duplicated one to eventMappings

```
Event[] public events;
    mapping (uint256 => Event) public eventMapping;
```